# Maven - Detect Multiple Versions of the Same Dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I just experienced a case of two direct dependencies of my maven project having two different versions of a particular transitive dependency.

In my particular case I had direct dependencies on the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jclouds.driver</groupId>
        <artifactId>jclouds-sshj</artifactId>
        <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Both of these dependencies had a (deep) transitive dependency on com.sun.jersey:jersey-core, but with different versions for each.  Maven didn't fail on this or even warn (or if it did, I never saw it!) that such a thing was happening... and as such I never noticed it until debugging a problem that happened when the version of jersey-core brought in by the jclouds dependency caused some things to break.

Is there a maven plugin or some other tool that exists that will detect this sort of deep transitive dependency overriding and at least warn the user (or fail the maven execution) if it detects such a collision... even if the default maven behavior is to just pick the first version that appears when resolving dependencies?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the Dependency Enforcer plugin. It will stop the build when dependencies don't converge properly.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce</id>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <DependencyConvergence />
          </rules>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: this appears to be exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't think to check the enforcer plugin for this.

Answer (score 6):

@Clement P has provided you with a perfectly good answer. Note however that it might be insufficient for multi-module projects.

The depedndencyconvergence goal of the enforcer plugin knows how to detect transitive dependency collisions, but a collision may hide itself in a different manner.

Suppose you have a multi-module project. Root is A and it has 2 sub modules, B1 and B2.

B1 declares a dependency on artifact **a:b:c:** *1.1*, while B2 declares a dependency on artifact **a:b:c:** *2.0*

In this case, if both modules are built and deployed with their dependencies- you will have a collision, but it is a kind the enforcer plugin does not know how to detect. Since project A doesn't (can't) depend on its sub modules.

In order to overcome this problem in our organization, we used the dependency:list plugin and analyzed its output manually.

Rough description of the process:The output of running this goal is a list of all transitive dependencies of all the projects in the project hierarchy. We than parse the output, sort the dependencies and search only for those artifacts that differ only by version id. This requires some scripting in your CI env but it is the only way for now to get the overall picture.

Answer (score 4):

you could run depenency report or use dependency tree:

> mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections

Answer (score 2):

You could just have a look at your `dependency hiercharchy` overview. This won't warn you, but you can see if certain versions are discarded for newer versions of the same library.

Comment: are you referring to running dependency:tree with verbose specified as @DmitryB suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve the version conflict by excluding the non wanted version from the apropriate dependency. For example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jclouds.driver</groupId>
    <artifactId>jclouds-sshj</artifactId>
    <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Or you add com.sun.jersey:jersey-core with the wanted version to your dependencies. Maven resolves version confilicts by supporting the dependency which is closest to the dependencies root.

Comment: I know how to resolve the problem.  What I want is for maven to tell me there is a *potential* problem to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

@Vitaly

my quickly hand-made command line to detect multiple versions of the same dependency :

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep ":compile" | sed 's/.* \(.*\):compile/\1/' | sort -u | cut -d ':' -f '1 2' | uniq -c | grep -vE "^ *1"
```

then, we can use the following command line to get used versions of theses dependencies (it isn't an optimized command line ;) :

```
for dep in $(mvn dependency:tree | grep ":compile" | sed 's/.* \(.*\):compile/\1/' | sort -u | cut -d ':' -f '1 2' | uniq -c | grep -vE "^ *1" | cut -d ' ' -f 8); 
do 
  echo $dep; 
  mvn dependency:tree | grep $dep; 
  echo 
done
```