# Exception in Springboot maven Weblogic environment

Tags: maven, weblogic, guava, springfox

After adding Swagger2 in Spring Boot application an error is generated which says java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.asMap(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;)Ljava/util/Map;

1 ) Dependency for swagger is shown below.

```
 <dependency> <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId> 
        <version>2.6.1</version> <scope>compile</scope> </dependency> 
     <dependency> <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId> 
        <version>2.6.1</version> <scope>compile</scope> </dependency>
```

2) JPA version 2.1 is used

3)WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.3.0.0 is Used

4)maven

Please provide me a solution for this exception.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError is very clear. Something was compiled with one version of software (Google Collections) and at runtime you are trying to use a different version of that software, and a method is not there. Such questions have been answered on here before ...

Comment: This is typical of bundling *two* versions of Guava in your software. You can follow [these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9797626/180719) to find out and fix your build.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven - Detect Multiple Versions of the Same Dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797334/maven-detect-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dependency)